# Error when deploying shiny app on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I am encountering errors messages when attempting to deploy my app  shinyapps.io.

I am getting this error after deploying

```
This version of Shiny is designed to work with 'htmlwidgets' >= 1.5.
    Please upgrade via install.packages('htmlwidgets').

Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable


Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    between, first, last

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    transpose

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : ImportError: No module named pandas
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

This is the code I have written in app.R -the app works when I run it in my local

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(DT)
library(knitr)
library(data.table)
py_install("pandas")
boxing <- readRDS('boxingdatafull2.rds')
#reading model
p <- import("pandas")
cat_model <- py_load_object("catmodelsummary.pkl",pickle="pickle")
# cat_model <- p$read_pickle("catmodelsummary.pkl")
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(setBackgroundImage(src = "mayweather2.png"),
            headerPanel(fluidRow(
              column(offset = 5, width=5,
                     h2("Boxing Prediction App")),
              column(offset = 3, width = 7,
                     h5("Welcome to Emmanuel's boxing prediction app. Using this app you can get the probability of a fight ending in a given way. The model used to derive these predictions uses data extracted before the 23rd of November 2019. Any updates to the data will be shown here. Without further ado, let's get ready to rumble!"))
            )),
            fluidRow(column(offset = 5, width = 2,align="center",
                            titlePanel(h5(selectInput("dropdown","Select Boxer Weights",choices=unique(boxing$division)))))),
            fluidRow(column(offset = 3, width=3,
                            wellPanel(
                              fluidRow(
                                uiOutput("Names"),
                                uiOutput("boxerA")))),
                     column(width = 3, align="right",
                            wellPanel(style = "height:300px",
                                      fluidRow(
                                        uiOutput("Opponent"),
                                        uiOutput("opppic")
                                      )))),
            hr(),
            column(offset=5,width = 8,
                   actionButton("goButton","Start Predictions")),
            hr(),
            column(offset=3,width=6,
                   DTOutput("predictions"))
            # ,
            # hr(),
            # column(offset=5,width = 5, 
            #        uiOutput("boxergifs"))
  ) 
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$Names <- renderUI({
    req(input$dropdown)
    df <- boxing %>% filter(division %in% input$dropdown)
    selectInput("names","Boxer A",choices = df$name)
  })
  output$boxerA <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src=paste(boxing[boxing$name == input$names, "global_id"],".jpg",sep=""),width=150)
  })
  output$Opponent <- renderUI({
    req(input$dropdown)
    df <- boxing %>% filter(division %in% input$dropdown)
    selectInput("names2","Opponent",choices = df$name)
  })
  output$opppic <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src=paste(boxing[boxing$name == input$names2, "global_id"],".jpg",sep=""),width=150)
  })

  observeEvent(input$goButton, {

    output$predictions <- renderDataTable({
      df1 <- boxing %>% filter(name %in% input$names)
      df2 <- boxing %>% filter(name %in% input$names2)
      df2$opp_loss <- df2$Loss.KO + df2$Loss.Other
      df2$opp_win <- df2$Win.KO + df2$Win.Other
      df1 <- df1 %>% select(Win.KO,Loss.Other,Loss.KO,Win.Other,KO.ratio,KnockedOut.ratio,Draw)
      df2 <- df2 %>% select(last6,KO.ratio,Win.Other,Win.KO,opp_loss,Loss.Other,opp_win,Loss.KO)
      setnames(df1,c("Win.KO","Loss.Other","Loss.KO","Win.Other","KO.ratio","KnockedOut.ratio"),c("winKO","lossOther","lossKO","winOther","KOratio","Knockedoutratio"))
      setnames(df2,c("last6","KO.ratio","Win.Other","Win.KO","Loss.Other","Loss.KO"), c("opp_last6","oppKOratio","opp_winOther","opp_winKO","opp_lossOther","opp_lossKO"))
      preds <- df1[,c("winKO","lossOther","lossKO","winOther","KOratio","Knockedoutratio","Draw")]
      preds2 <- df2[,c("opp_last6","oppKOratio","opp_winOther","opp_winKO","opp_loss","opp_lossOther","opp_win","opp_lossKO")]
      preds3 <- bind_cols(preds,preds2)
      df <- data.frame(probs = round(cat_model$predict_proba(preds3)*100,2))
      names(df)[1] <- "Draw"
      names(df)[2] <- "Loss"
      names(df)[3] <- "Win"
      #custom table
      datatable(df, container = htmltools::withTags(table(tableHeader(df))),options = list(pageLength=1,dom='tip'), rownames = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe')
    })

  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

UPDATE:

After upgrading htmlwidgets and python as suggested in one of the comments. I am not getting this error message upon deploying my app

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: that seems pretty straightforward to me: upgrade the package ```htmlwidgets``` and upgrade python

Comment: @bretauv still getting an error ->Error in value[[3L]](cond) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted